# Flask app.before_request to ignore routes that don't exist

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

For each request I am checking to see if the app is in maintenance mode, I am doing this because if there is some kind of bug I can easily put the app into this mode and it will inform the users of the state.

However, even when a route does not exist the before check is performed.

Is it possible to ignore this particular check when a route doesn't exist and for the fallback route to take over and inform the user it does not exit.

Before request maintenance check:

```
@app.before_request
def maintenance_mode():
    maintenance = yaml.safe_load(open(app.root_path + '/maintenance.yml'))
    if maintenance['status']:
        raise MaintenanceMode()
```

Fallback:

```
@app.route('/<path:fallback>')
def fallback_catcher(fallback):
    raise FallbackNotFound()
```

Comment: You can get a list of url routes using `app.url_map.iter_rules()`.  You'd have to do some regex to test for url variables, like `/products/shoes/12345` == `/products/shoes/<itemnum>`.  Why not use `after_request`?

Comment: @GAEfan Use after request for what?

Comment: If `after_request`, any bad URL would get handled as you currently do. Others you could `return render_template('maintenance.html')`

Comment: The problem gets a lot simpler if you delay handing out 404s until the app is out of maintenance mode. Especially if maintenance mode might be introducing new routes or removing old ones. Also, you can save work by recording the last time `maintenance.yml` was modified, and then use `os.stat` to check the current modification time, reading the file only if that modification time has changed.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Yeah, I'll probably just leave it as is and serve 503. Very good idea! Would this have any kind of performance improvements over reading the file every time?

Comment: Depends on the OS. On most, `os.stat` can be answered out of data structures related to the directory (e.g., a linux inode), which is going to be a cheaper operation than sucking the file in and de-yaml'ing it.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I am running Ubuntu Bionic Beaver for development. Will probably use the same for production because of the Nginx plugins available. Definitely implementing this though. Thank you :) ☺️